# Rectifiable curves admit Lipschitz reparametrizations

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, curves, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $X$ is a metric space with distance function $d\colon X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$. It is stated [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rectifiable_curve) that if a continuous curve $\alpha\colon [0,1]\to X$ has finite length, then it admits a Lipschitz parametrization, i.e., there exists a homeomorphism $g\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $\alpha \circ g$ is a Lipschitz map. I'm interested in finding a proof for this result.

So far, I've been able to prove a weaker version of this statement: Let $L=\mathcal{L}_{0}^{1}(\alpha)$ be the total length of $\alpha$. The function $g\colon [0,1]\to [0,L]$ given by $g(s)=\mathcal{L}_{0}^{s}(\alpha)$ is a surjective, nondecreasing continuous function. If we assume that $\alpha$ is nonconstant in every subinterval $[a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$, then $g$ is a homeomorphism, and $\alpha \circ g^{-1}\colon [0,L]\to X$ is a unit speed parametrization of $\alpha$, hence Lipschitz. If we don't assume this, at least it's possible to see that $\alpha$ passes continuously to a $1$-Lipschitz function $\beta\colon [0,L]\to X$ such that $\alpha = \beta \circ g$, which is not quite the same as what's stated in the result, since $g$ is not a homeomorphism.

Can anyone give me a reference or an outline of the proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is just the arc-length parameterization. The fact that it is 1-Lipschitz is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: But if we only assume that $\alpha$ is continous, the arc-lenght function is not a homeomorphism, so how can we make that idea work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be your rectifiable curve of length $L$, connecting point $p$ to a point $q$. Given $s\in [0, L]$, there is a unique point $x\in \alpha$ such that the 1-dimensional measure of $\alpha$ between $p$ and $x$ equals $s$. The map $f: s\mapsto x$ is called the *arc-length parameterization* of $\alpha$. The map $f$ is a homeomorphism and is 1-Lipschitz.

Comment: I see, thank you! Just one thing, do s and t always differ by a homeomorphism?

Comment: @DarthLubinus: It depends on what you mean by $s$ and $t$.

Comment: More formally: i have that $\alpha$ is the original curve, with a given parametrization (i.e. $\alpha\colon [0,1]\to X$ is a continuous, map which depends on $t$), and $f\colon [0,L]\to X$ is the arc-length parametrization of $\alpha$, depending on $s$. Does there exist a homeomorphism $g\colon [0,L]\to [0,1]$ such that $\alpha \circ g=f$?

Comment: @DarthLubinus: Then yes. However, in my answer I was working under the assumption that the original map $\alpha$ is 1-1, otherwise, the notion of a rectifiable curve becomes ambiguous (this was missing from the linked Encyclopedia article).